# npm ERR! The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type object in laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel-5, npm

When I try to run npm install in a project created by Laravel 5.6, I had this error. This is on Ubuntu 18.4

[image: Here's a screenshot of the problem]

Comment: Can you share what your `package.json` looks like?

Comment: that is my package.json

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtDt4.png